# How to create and run Visual Basic Code on Mac in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out, but I just can't seem to. I hope you have the patience to read my problems and help me fix them.

I am taking a Visual Basic course online for my school. Since our school has no PC and just Macs, I am running into a few issues. Our teacher wants us to use Visual Studio, which I have downloaded for Mac.

We were told to create a project using Visual Basic. I followed the instructor and attempted to do what he did.

I open Visual Studio, create a new project, select the code to be VB (not C# or anything else) and prepare to start coding. I start to type and I am not able to as a pop up box says "No completions found".

All I want to do is just make my code in a .vb file (which is the format the teacher wants... will they accept a vb.NET file, idk what that is) and be able to run it in Visual Studio.

But nothing is working out for me. All the tutorials online show how to create projects in Mac and run them, but for C#. I did research and it said to download Mono, and I did, but I don't know what to do with it.

If anyone can please help, I will be fulfilled with tremendous gratitude. Thank you.

Comment: VB.NET is not the first batch of languages to be supported on .NET Core. You have to use C# or F#.

Comment: Shouldn't your teacher help you getting this to work? By the way, are you using [**Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or from where did you get the IDE?

Comment: Information about Visual Basic on Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/

Comment: Thanks guys. That actually helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET is not the first batch of languages to be supported on VS Code. You should use C# or F# instead.

These are supported programming languages for Visual Studio Code at the moment :
**JavaScript, JSON, HTML, CSS, Sass, Less, TypeScript, Markdown, PHP, Python, Go, Dockerfile, T-SQL, C#, C++**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use another program called Rider from Jetbrains. You are a student so you can use Rider for free.

http://www.jetbrains.com/rider/

You can choose for Library projects and console app projects, but that is for a start more than enough.

[image: Jetbrains Rider]

Answer (score -3):

First of all, you can't just edit the desktop application in VB.Net on mac Visual Studio...  while downloading Visual Studio they ask a question on their site " I want this application for" and there is no option provided there to download and run VB.Net on the mac so the answer is:

No, you can't run a VB.Net program on mac with creating windows form.

Comment: Please remember that we are here to help  - it is preferable to be courteous (no shouting!).

Comment: Also, this is incorrect.  It is entirely possible to run/build a VB.NET app on Mac OS using Windows forms.  The Mono framework can be used for this (amongst other frameworks)